# Embedded Python Block not reading parameter value

Tags: python, gnuradio

I am trying to code the Embedded Python Block in GNU Radio to accept a vector length size as defined by the user in a parameter field that opens when the block is clicked (as usual). However, as stated in the issue here ( https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/issues/4196 ), the scheduler of GNU Radio doesn't seem to pick up the value a user enters until later in the process, making my vector length the default value from the `__init__` function and screwing up my code.

Currently, I have tried to implement the solution provided by Djgreene730 in https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/issues/4196, but because I lack a deeper understanding of the GRC library (and coding in general, I'm an electrical engineer, not a computer engineer or scientist), I have been unable to implement this code or debug it (though I am sure there are no issue with it and GRC is just being finicky). My current understanding of this code is that it just gets the name of the flowgraph variable I want, but I want the value of it.
My current goal is to write a function that will search the flowgraph and find the variable I want, then extract the value from it so I can use it inside my `__init__` function to overwrite the default value.
My current solution is to change the default value in the code editor every time I change the vector length.
My end goal is to make this code/flowgraph "user friendly" such that the user doesn't need an IDE to change the value.

Here is my current code (note: "test code" is the same code provided by Djgreene730):

```
import numpy as np
from gnuradio import gr

#WindowSize = 1000000

# *** BEGINNING OF TEST CODE ***


def get_top_variable(variable_name="WindowSize", default=None):
    '''
    Returns the value of a variable from the flow graph.
    '''

    # Let's go!
    try:
        ## Run Condition: GNURadio is starting the flowgraph
        top = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back.f_locals

        # Check if top has the variable name we're looking for
        if top.__contains__(variable_name):

            # Let the user know we found the variable
            print(f"[Block Debug] While starting, I found top variable \'{variable_name}\': type={type(top[variable_name])}, value={top[variable_name]}")

            # Return the value of the variable name
            return top[variable_name]

        ## Run Condition: Saving the flowgraph
        top = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back.f_back.f_back.f_back.f_locals

        # Make sure top has 'self'
        if top.__contains__("self") and \
                (isinstance(top['self'], grc.gui.canvas.flowgraph.FlowGraph)) and \
                (hasattr(top['self'], 'blocks')):

            # Get a list of all blocks
            block_names = [block.name for block in top['self'].blocks]

            # Find the index to the variable we need
            block_index = block_names.index(variable_name)

            # Store the result
            result = top['self'].blocks[block_index].params['value'].value

            # Let the user know we found the variable
            print(f"[Block Debug] While modifying the flowgraph, I found top variable \'{variable_name}\': type={type(result)}, value={result}")

            # Return the value of the variable we found
            return result

    # Something went wrong
    except Exception as e:
        print("[Block Debug]: Threw an exception", e)
    except:
        print("[Block Debug]: Threw an unknown exception.")

    # Return the default result
    return default


# *** ENDING OF TEST CODE ***


class blk(gr.sync_block):  # other base classes are basic_block, decim_block, interp_block
    """Embedded Python Block example - a simple multiply const"""

    def __init__(self, window_size = get_top_variable("vlen", default=1)): # = 1  # only default arguments here
        # note on the window_size value: internal, need to get an external variable and sub it in

 #       # *** TEST CODE BEGIN ***
        
        # Get packet length
        vlen = get_top_variable("vlen", default=1)
        print(f"[Block Debug] Setting input length using \'vlen\': {vlen}, type={type(vlen)}")
        
 #       # *** TEST CODE END ***


        """arguments to this function show up as parameters in GRC"""
        gr.sync_block.__init__(
            self,
            name='Modulation Monitor',   # will show up in GRC
            in_sig=[(np.complex64, window_size)],
            out_sig=[(np.complex64, window_size)] 

        )
        # if an attribute with the same name as a parameter is found,
        # a callback is registered (properties work, too).
```

(left out the `work()` code since it isn't the problem)